# Ubuntu 16.04 desktop DNS configured over DHCP resolves only sporadically

Tags: networking, 16.04, dns, dhcp

Hi there I just freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04, gnome edition. In my network, a Windows 2012 R2 server is AD, DHCP and primary DNS.  My router is secondary DNS. My client picks up the right addresses in the right orders and was able to resolve every host on my LAN. I was even able to join AD using sssd and realmd.

However now I am experiencing troubles to propperly resolve DNS names. 
All other clients resolve correctly (windows, osx, ios, ubuntu server with static configuration). Ubuntu desktop does wired things:

- Sometimes it resolves propperly
- sometimes it doesn't resolve at all.
- sometimes it picks up avahi from my router (can't be disabled on the router...)

while at all times it is showing the correct configuration in the network manager: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW2aL.png).
Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong or where the root cause might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it seems I found my problem. Ubuntu is using dnsmasq along with network manager to perform DNS caching. When i disable it in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` by commenting out `dns=dnsmasq` everything works fine again. 
Wondering where this is coming from.

If I don't get any feedback from you guys telling me I did some terrible thing, I will accept this as the valid solution.